# How to upload image using POST method to server in wp7 using php webservice?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to upload image file while is selected from PhotoChooser in Windows Phone 7 but it is not getting uploaded. I am using following code.

```
     void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
    {
        UriBuilder ub = new  UriBuilder("http://webservice.php?uid=" + Constants.UserId);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=7794b1e4-2134-41a3-b8ab-ff5aff9710fd";

        webClient.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("START");
            PushData(data, e.Result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("END");
            e.Result.Close();
            data.Close();
        };
        webClient.WriteStreamClosed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WriteStreamClosed");
        };
        webClient.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
    }

    private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("--7794b1e4-2134-41a3-b8ab-ff5aff9710fd\r\n"
            + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadFile\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\n"
            + "Content-Type:Image/jpeg\r\n\r\n");
        output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        int dd = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            dd += bytesRead;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WRITE: " + dd);
        }
        bytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n--7794b1e4-2134-41a3-b8ab-ff5aff9710fd--\r\n");
        output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in above code?

Comment: I don't see a problem right away, but we could do with a few more details. You said this POST isn't uploading data, but what are the actual symptoms? Do you get an exception? (I don't see any try-catch blocks, if that's the case.) You've got some diagnostics, what are the results? Have you stepped through the code to do a sanity check on some key values? Do you know that the http://webservice.php is actually getting called? (E.g., attach a debugger to the service and set a breakpoint, or perform some tracing/logging.)

Comment: BTW, the fact that the service is written in PHP should have no bearing on how a POST works. HTTP is platform-, language- and vendor-neutral. I am reasonably sure that detail is a red herring.

Comment: it is not throwing any exception and i have debug the code but i am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: bhai mara badha que and ans vote down kari didha chhe te... sudharo have..